# How do I know what Xcode versions are supported in Homebrew for my specific macOS version?

Tags: macos, xcode, homebrew

When trying to use `brew` on older macOS version 10.14 Mojave, I got the error message:

```
Error: Your Xcode (10.0) is too outdated.
Please update to Xcode 11.3.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.
```

How do I know which Xcode versions are supported by `brew` on macOS 10.14? On any version? (Preferably, without installing Xcode and checking.)

Answer (score 2):

The runtime error message prints the **maximum** version for macOS 10.14:

> Please update to Xcode 11.3.1

---

I don't think `brew` documentation contain the supported Xcode version information, but the [current source code `xcode.rb`](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/xcode.rb) contains the data in switch-case blocks.

Supported versions for Xcode.app are defined in the [`‎OS::Mac::Xcode` module](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/4.1.7/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/xcode.rb#L19-L56) with `latest_version` through `minimum_version`:

```ruby
      def self.latest_version(macos: MacOS.version)
        latest_stable = "14.3"
        case macos
        when "14" then "15.0"
        when "13" then latest_stable
        when "12" then "14.2"
        when "11" then "13.2.1"
        when "10.15" then "12.4"
        when "10.14" then "11.3.1"
      ...

      def minimum_version
        case MacOS.version
        when "14" then "15.0"
        when "13" then "14.1"
        when "12" then "13.1"
        when "11" then "12.2"
        when "10.15" then "11.0"
        when "10.14" then "10.2"
      ...
```

so `brew` thinks any version from Xcode version `10.2` through `11.3.1` will work on macOS 10.14.

There's seprate code for the Command Line Tools (CLT) in [`‎OS::Mac::CLT::minimum_version`](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/4.1.7/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/xcode.rb#L359) which says the minimum Xcode version is `10.0.0`.

Comment: This is [a better link to self.minimal_version()](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/xcode.rb#L26) Ruby function from brew. Thanks!